# What does $\text{mod}\ m$ in $a \equiv b (\text{mod}\ m)$ means

Tags: definition

I am trying to do example 3.6 from this http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~lacher/courses/MAD3105/lectures/s1_3equivrel.pdf script, but I am not sure what does $(\text{mod}\ m)$ means.

Can somebody explain it to me. Thanks.

Comment: $a\equiv b\pmod m$ means that $a-b$ is an integer multiple of $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m\mid a-b$ as a whole meaning of $a\equiv b$ mod (m)

Answer (score 1):

a= k*m + b ; b is the rest of the euclidian division of a by m

Comment: Not true. If it were $\ b = (a\ {\rm mod}\ m)\ $ then you could say that $\,b\,$ is the remainder of $\,a\,$ modulo $\,m.\,$ But the notation $\,a\equiv b\pmod{m}\,$ means precisely that $\,m\mid a-b,\,$ which does not imply anything about the size of $\,a,b.\ \ $